# Nominal size (shrinkage) for 3 x 12 porcelain tile bullnose trim?

Tags: tile, trim, porcelain

What is the range of acceptable shrinkage for porcelain tile trim?

The trim is advertised at the supplier site as 3" x 12"; the actual trim is 2 5/8" x 11 3/4".

I did some online research before posting. The first answers I found suggested that shrinkage should be "small," and that porcelain shrinks less than ceramic. But then searching for porcelain shrinkage information resulted in plenty of hits for ceramic shrinkage. Arrrgggh.

Note: This post is related to this one:

[Bullnose tile trim installation problem: feasible fix, feasible concession, or neither?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/138437/bullnose-tile-trim-installation-problem-feasible-fix-feasible-concession-or-n)

Comment: In all cases the "trim" should be close to the "advertised" size. As far as I know once fired there is no shrinkage. If you get your calipers out I think you should watch 200/300 U tube videos so you have a clue!  Tile can vary by type and size, if there is changes/ cracks, broken tiles for example the installer is probably the problem in my opinion.

Comment: From what I've seen, tile dimensions are often specified as the measurement from one edge to the same edge on the next tile - which includes the nominal/recommended grout spacing. So a 3" nominal tile which actually measures 2-5/8" is expected to have 3/8" of grout between tiles.